# No local DataSource found for configuration - 'dataSource' property must be set on LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3.6 
 DataSource is defined as

```
<bean id="test-pool"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:sqlserver://Machine:1433;databaseName=TEST;maxPoolSize=100;
                minPoolSize=5;acquireIncrement=5;checkoutTimeout=5000;maxStatements=100;idleConnectionTestPeriod=3000" />
            <property name="username" value="${user}" />
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>

    </bean>
```

Session Factory with data source is

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="test-pool"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/classes/test.hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In Factory class:

```
LocalSessionFactoryBean localfactorybean = (LocalSessionFactoryBean)AppContext.getBean("&sessionFactory");
        Configuration configuration = localfactorybean.getConfiguration();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

But I am getting following exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No local DataSource found for configuration - 'dataSource' property must be set on LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.configure(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91)
```

What is wrong with my current code?

I get rid of this exception if I explicitly get SessionFactory again like this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) AppContext.getBean("sessionFactory");
```

As you can see its not neat and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Is there something else nested in your exception?  What you have looks good.  I expect spring is failing to create your datasource (maybe it can't find the driver jar) and there is more detail somewhwere

Comment: @hvgotcodes Please refer my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exact version of Hibernate are you using? [This article](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2909) suggests that there is a problem with 3.2.1 which has the same symptoms as you have. Maybe time to update your version - hibernate is now at 4.1.4

Comment: I am using Hibernate 3 and can not upgrade my version. We are using few hibernate 3 specific classes deep in our code which are not available in Hibernate 4.

Comment: OK, well the article says that 3.2.2 fixed the problem so you could stick with Hibernate 3. It's worth a quick check that you haven't got an earlier version.

Comment: Sure I will try Hibernate 3.2.2 and If it works thanks in advance :)

Comment: Application has Hibernate version 3.6